# Invalid nib registered for identifier ((null)) - nib must contain exactly one top level

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm using a custom `UITableViewCell`. When I try to run my code, I got this exception stack and I can't understand the source of the problem:

```
terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'invalid nib registered for identifier ((null)) - nib must contain exactly one top level object which must be a UITableViewCell instance'
```

Please note I am not using Storyboard.

**EDIT:**

This is my relevant code which cause the problem according to the breakpoint:

```
[tableviewSupport registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"HotelCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellReuseIdentifier:CustomCellCId];
```

Comment: I suggest breaking that code line in two for debugging purposes.  Load the UINib object into a variable and test whether that was successful before trying to register it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do in your provided code. You will unload your nib in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:. You can use the below code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Assuming you set a reuse identifier "cellId" in the nib for your table view cell...
    HotelCell *cell = (HotelCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellId"];
    if (!cell) {
        // If you didn't get a valid cell reference back, unload a cell from the nib
        NSArray *nibArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"HotelCell" owner:nil options:nil];
        for (id obj in nibArray) {
            if ([obj isMemberOfClass:[HotelCell class]]) {
                // Assign cell to obj
                cell = (HotelCell *)obj;
                break;
            }
        }
     }

     return cell;
}
```

Now, based on the error you posted, iOS is expecting a single object in the array, so the for loop may be unnecessary. I've done this by checking if [nibArray count] == 1 and then grabbing the objectAtIndex:0 and assigning it to cell instead of looping, and this works as well. But, if one day Apple decides to stick something else in that nibArray, a for loop protects you against that.

Comment: if you use IOS6, try dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: and be happy. to verify if cell is nil no longer necessary

Answer (score 31):

Another solution:

I had UITableViewCell, but in my XIB there was an extra object, a label which I had misplaced.

So check your XIB carefully to make sure there is only one object in the object table on the left side.

[image]

Comment: yep, I had a Button just sitting there

Comment: Thank you, this answer just put an end to about three hours of seemingly hopeless debugging. I thought I had deleted the default view from the file that IB generated, but turns out I had only hidden it.

Comment: wow. This is a classic example how something simple can help you save hours of debugging. Thank you.

Comment: but I think that is more better put a couple UITableViewCell into one single Nib file..... that will be more easy to maintains

Comment: Thank you very much for posting this. Would never have spotted it.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you.
But my problem is that I had a UIGestureRecognizer registered there and does that mean I have to remove and implement it in code?

Comment: Thank you very much!, Problem solved, i left two cell designs in one xib, now i separate them into two.  all good now XD

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer to the OP's question, but I had the same error with a different solution, so I'll answer this question for the sake of Googlers who come hereafter.

I *did* have a single `UITableViewCell` (actually, my own subclass) in my XIB -- so I couldn't understand why it wasn't working.

The key seems to be:

When you've created a XIB file with a single `UITableViewCell` or subclass (e.g. if you drag on a UITableViewCell from the library on the lower right), Interface Builder shows you an option under the "Table View Cell" section of the Inspector tab.

I usually used to create a UIView and changing its type to my UITableViewCell subclass, so I had never noticed that option.

It is ***there*** that you need to type the identifier (as well as in your `registerNib:withReuseIdentifer:` call).

More frustrating for me when experiencing this was that it didn't crash *EVERY* time, only the first time.  Weird.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I set a property with name class (for eg: @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *class) in tableviewcell, this give above mention error , then name "class" is not objective c type, change (class = classabc) resolve above issue.